# Creating a NuGet Package that updates the MSBUILD process to run a program before the build target

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, pre-build-event

I'm trying to create a *NuGet* package that runs an external application before build. That application creates a *compilationtime.h* file to know the time of compilation to show it in the *About* dialog box.

My NuGet package has a *Tools* folder with the *CreateCompilationTimeFile.exe* and an *Build* folder with *{packagename}.props* file.

I've tried a lot of combinations to create the Pre-Build event in the *{packagename}.props* file but none of them is working.

I tried with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
      <Command>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\CreateCompilationTimeFile.exe"</Command>
    </PreBuildEvent>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

Also with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild2" BeforeTargets="Build">
      <Exec Command="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\CreateCompilationTimeFile.exe"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

If I do it without the NuGet package and I do it with the next property sheet, it works correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
      <Command>"$(SolutionDir)Tools\CreateCompilationTimeFile.exe"</Command>
    </PreBuildEvent>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

But I want to do it with the NuGet package and not with property sheets.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Your second method `<Target Name="BeforeBuild2" BeforeTargets="Build">` should be work, why it is not working for you? Do you have any error for this method?

Comment: No, I don't have any errors, but the pre-build event never runs and the file "compilationtime.h" is never created.

Comment: pre-build event never runs, you make me confused. If you are use the second method, there is no any pre-build event, it replaced by the target `<Target Name="BeforeBuild2" BeforeTargets="Build">`, am I right? when you build your project, VS/MSBuild will execute this target before build, the CreateCompilationTimeFile.exe will be executed and generate the the file "compilationtime.h". Do I have any misunderstandings?

Comment: Or creating a Pre-Build event in a NuGet Package is your goal instead of creating a NuGet package that runs an external application before build?

Comment: With the second method there is effectively no "pre-build event", and indeed the program should be executed, but it is not executed. Sorry about misunderstanding.

Comment: I just realized that It's working but only when I rebuild the project. If I just Build the project, the program is not executed, but when rebuild it's executed correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180011/discussion-between-joseangelmt-and-leo-liu-msft).

Comment: Glad to know you have resolved this issue, please convert your update info to the answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread. Thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @leo-liu-msft says, the second solution works, but it's not working as expected, as I will explain below.

If the *{packagename}.props* contains this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CreateCompilationFileTimeTarget" BeforeTargets="Build">
      <Exec Command="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\CreateCompilationTimeFile.exe"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Suppose that you just created a brand new C++ project and include *compilationtime.h* file in one of your .cpp files:

```
#include "compilationtime.h"
```

Remember, the project is **new** and you don't have any *compilationtime.h* file jet, it is supposed to be created **before** the build process because of the {packagename}.props.

If you build your C++ project, you'll get a *C0183 Cannot open include file: 'CompilationTime.h': No such file or directory* error.

If then you open the project folder, the *compilationtime.h* file is not where it supposes to be.

Now comment the `#include "compilationfile.h"` line and compile it again. The compiler will finish without any errors and if you analyze the folder, the file will be there!

Now that your *compilationfile.h* already exists, edit it and change the tm_year to 0 for example:

```
#pragma once
static struct tm GetCompilationTime()
{
    struct tm compilationTime = { 0 };
    compilationTime.tm_year=0;
    compilationTime.tm_mon=9;
    compilationTime.tm_mday=15;
    compilationTime.tm_hour=15;
    compilationTime.tm_min=37;
    compilationTime.tm_sec=41;
    return compilationTime;
}
```

..and then in your .cpp file, print the year to the console:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "CompilationTime.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << GetCompilationTime().tm_year << std::endl;
}
```

Compile and run the program. The program **will print 0** and not the current year, but if you open the *compilationtime.h* file, it is modified with the current year, so the compiler is behaving as if instead of `BeforeTargets="Build"` we had configured `AfterTargets="Build"`.

Finally I solved the problem changing the *BeforeTargets* to **PrepareForBuild** like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Target Name="CreateCompilationFileTimeTarget" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
        <Exec Command="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\tools\CreateCompilationTimeFile.exe"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

and now it creates/updates the *compilationtime.h* file always before build as I wanted.